# How to convert Ruby on Rails Model to a .json file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, models, learn-ruby-on-rails

If I have a basic ruby on rails model set up (like for example the typical blogpost application) with an `index` action like:

```
def index
  @blogs=Blog.all
end
```

How do I convert all the blogs into a `.json` file? 
I know if I do:

```
def index
  @blogs=Blog.all
  respond_to do |format| 
  format.html{}
  format.json{render json: @blogs.to_json}
end
```

This will give a json output (what I want) but at the following path: /blogs.json in my browser, but I want an actual .json file (not just one being visible in browser at a path).

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Did you mean a json file to be downloaded?

Comment: if thats what it would take then yes.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want the browser to prompt the user to download a `.json` file rather than displaying it? Or do you want to write the data to a `.json` file on the machine the server is running on? If the latter, do you just want to do it once, or have a command you can use to do it frequently?

Comment: ActiveRecord seems to have had a to_json method that would serialize a model as json file, but it's since been deprecated. You may wish to look at http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/ActiveSupport/JSON/Encoding/JSONGemEncoder

Comment: If all you want to do is return a json response from that url by default (not html) then just remove the `format.html{}` line or if you want to still be able to get an html version (at .html) set the default format in the routes file ala `resources :blogs, :defaults => { :format => :json }`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
 format.json{render json: @blogs.to_json}
```

by

```
format.json{send_data @blogs.to_json}
```